# And the joke was NOT a joke

Tags: general-pedagogy, students-mistakes

*This is not a question; so I perfectly understand that it could be deleted almost immediately.*

Yesterday, I was attending a New Year eve party and I was introduced to a young and brilliant lawyer. Hearing that I am (*supposed to be*) a mathematician, he seriously told me : "So, could you, by the end, explain to me why is $ax^2+bx+c$ always equal to $0$?".

I took it as a very good joke. The problem is that this was not a joke at all : the guy was serious !!

I am not an educator but I think that there are a lot of questions coming out from it.

I would really appreciate your opinions.

Since questions are required :

**what can we do to make better understanding of mathematics starting with young people** ?

**how can we make mathematics more attractive ?**

Comment: Could you perhaps formulate a question that you think arises from the lawyer's question/possible misconception? That would be something the community might be able to answer.

Comment: @JW. I really don't think what to ask as a question (could you help me to formulate one ?). I discovered again how poorly can be explained things by bad educators (I suffered many of them myself). Nobody ever told me that mathematics includes beauty and fun plus many other pleasant things I learned with age.

Comment: I can think of a few possibilities for questions, but I'm not sure any are quite suitable for here: What can we do (if anything) about the current adult population that has this misunderstanding? How best (if at all) can we prevent the younger generation being left with it too? What techniques have people tried to explain what is going on here? Does any research look into whether this is because of mis-teaching (or simply teaching-to-the-test) vs. students ignoring what they've been told? Is there a comical way of explaining the answer (or at least showing the error), using maths or otherwise?

Comment: @JessicaB. Thanks for answering ! Many people think (and I was among them !) that mathematics is a punishment to suffer at school. When I say that I am a mathematician (even if not totally true), the most immediate reaction is : "So, you are a teacher !". When I try to explain that, just having fun for all my life, I made majors companies savings millions (and more) of dollars thanks to some minor mathematical work, they don't trust me !! Please, go ahead with some possibilities for questions here. By the way, **Happy New Year !!**.

Comment: You got proposals for some questions. If you want to ask one of them please [edit] the post to include it.  I am afraid we cannot keep this post open "as is." As you know SE is for questions (and answers) not open ended discussions.

Comment: @quid. I perfectly understand. I added a question.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I am sorry.  These questions you added are much too broad and seem  unrelated to the example you gave.

Comment: @quid. No problem at all. I was just hoping that we could share ideas between the members of this nice community.

Comment: Another possibility for a question, although perhaps not what you had in mind, is the one the lawyer posed. A related alternative could be to ask for good ways of motivating why one should care about finding roots of polynomials (or something of that ilk).

Comment: I like the spirit of this.  I agree things are too broad though. I  believe that most students  are interested in maths initially but are later switched off.

Comment: Equating the expression to 0 allows the solution of the equation using factoring.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche. May be, I did not explain properly : the guy was wondering why $ax^2+bx+c$ is **always** equal to $0$.

Comment: I think the needed word is "normal form".

Comment: You could simply tell the truth and say "It doesn't". This puts the work of the conversation on him to say more about the context. Maybe his REAL question is why it seems we always want to write it to be equal to $0.$ You could also respond with something like: "Why do we always have $x$ equal to a number? Why not $3x$ equal to a number, or $5x-2$ equal to a number? Oh, wait. We do have these . . ." (and let this sink in).

Comment: Perhaps he is wondering why you don't need to solve linear equations by having he equals zero but for quadratic you do. What changed? I'd like to discuss this further but perhaps in a free flowing format

Comment: Actually, it makes a pretty good joke…students seem to think this is the case! Any time they encounter a quadratic polynomial they set it to zero.

Comment: @JonBannon: And that, sadly, is because most are not **interested** in the features of the quadratic, but rather are hoping that by mimicking what their teacher appears to do and often even teaches wrongly by saying "and now we set it to zero", they can score more marks. If only **teachers** truly teach mathematics for what it really is, namely an open-ended non-routine search for (mathematical) **truths**, then the problem will vanish. But if this sounds like wishful thinking to any teacher, this problem will remain.

Comment: @user21820. Good point.